# why does this iterate the div twice?

Tags: jquery, image, iteration, erb

So I've created an erb block that iterates through the coordinates for each image tag ('.tagged'), and then displays '.tagged' for each image at the given coordinates. In this particular case the block iterates through 2 images, and .tagged shows up on both images instead of one tag per respected image. Is this because of the .each() method?

```
<div class="container">
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>

<span class="i_connection" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>"> </span>
<br>
<div class="image_panel">
    <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class='planetmap'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("span.i_connection").each(function() {
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    $(".tagged_box").css("display","block");
    $(".tagged").css("border","5px solid red");

        $('.planetmap').append('<div class="tagged"  style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+pos_height+'px;left:'+xpos+'px;top:'+ypos+'px;" ><div class="tagged_box" style="width:'+pos_width+'px;height:'+
            pos_height+'px;" ></div>')
});   //END OF SPAN.CONNECTION ITERATION
}); //END OF JQUERY
</script>   
<% end %>   
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML markup, it's impossible to answer your question. Could you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: I made a gist, just cause it would be quicker :)
https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6050853

Comment: Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/44r5v/ Can you explain to me what the desired outcome is versus what I'm seeing?

Comment: From your gist, it appears you are generating the jquery script once per html block. Move it outside your html generation loop, so the `$(document).ready( {...} );` function is only inserted into your page once.

Comment: In the fiddle, the red rectangles are the same exact size, whereas they should be the size of the numbers above their respected image (X coordinate, Y coordinate, Width, Height). And ideally at that position. When I run it locally with the erb block it generates something like this
http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/4055/wbng.png

Comment: @DomDay updated the gist with the jquery out of the block

Comment: ok, well, you're still generating `div.planetmap` twice. you need to move that outside the loop also. If your positioning of the elements you are appending to planetmap is off, be sure they are positioned absolutely. posting the relevant css might help

Comment: I thought I would need to generate .planetmap twice because the .tagged div is appended to it

Answer (score 0):

Move your block of javascript outside of the

```
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
```

loop.

Comment: I did, now .tagged is generated only once per image, but at the same coordinates for both. Any ideas?